# Подключение установленной библиотеки в Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

На Ubuntu 14.04.4 установил интерфейс pcsc-lite для работы со смарт-картами. Как правильно подключить данную библиотеку в свой проект в Makefile?
Нашел, вот такую запись, но что дальше делать с переменными `PCSC_CFLAGS` и `LDFLAGS`? Как **правильно** их подключить к сборке?

```
PCSC_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags libpcsclite)
LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs libpcsclite)
```

Не судите строго, пару недель на linux.

---

Добавлено:

Есть несколько файлов file1.cpp, file2.cpp, file3.cpp и main.cpp. Все это нужно собрать, плюс добавить библиотеку pcsc-lite.

```
PCSC_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags libpcsclite)
LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs libpcsclite)

SCR := file1.o file2.o file3.o 

test_project: main.cpp $(SCR)
    g++ -o test_project main.cpp $(SCR) $(PCSC_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

file1.o: file1.cpp
    g++ -c file1.cpp

file2.o: file2.cpp
    g++ -c file2.cpp

file3.o: file3.cpp
    g++ -c file3.cpp
```

Что я делаю не так? Поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это аргументы командной строки для вызова компилятора и компоновщика. В простейшем случае нужно просто написать `gcc список_файлов $$(pkg-config --libs --cflags libpcsclite)`. Но всё зависит от вашего Makefile. Добавьте, пожалуйста, его ключевые части в вопрос.

Comment: @mymedia, добавил Makefile. Все ли я сделал правильно? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: так команды `pkg-config --cflags libpcsclite` и `pkg-config --libs libpcsclite` возвращают что-нибудь полезное? // да и словосочетание *установил интерфейс pcsc-lite* требует расшифровки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, надеюсь, это означает установленный пакет libpcsclite-dev

Comment: @VadoM, какая возникает ошибка в вашем случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы написал Makefile похожий на такой

```
PCSC_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags libpcsclite)
PCSC_LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs libpcsclite)

SOURCES := main.cpp file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

test_project: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(OBJECTS) $(PCSC_LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(PCSC_CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Основная идея: Вывод утилиты pkg-config с ключом `--cflags` — это флаги компилятора, и их нужно передавать когда собираются объектные файлы из исходных; т.к. это в основном всякие подсказки, где искать подключаемые заголовки. Вывод с ключом `--libs` — это  флаги для компоновки, в данном случае список библиотек; его обязательно нужно передавать после объектных файлов.

Обратите внимание, что в этом куске кода вместо четырёх пробелов должен быть символ табуляции — здешний парсер своевольничает, подменяя символы (и подсветки почему-то нету ).

Почитать подробнее про Makefiles, я думаю, можно [перевод документации](http://rus-linux.net/nlib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/gnu_make/gnu_make_3-79_russian_manual.html). К сожалению, он про старую версию GNU Make, но поможет понять основы.
Краткую информацию о pkg-config можно найти в [этой заметке](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1443476). (Ничего более подходящего я не нашёл, можете почитать руководство [pkg-config(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pkg-config.1.html), чтобы получше разобраться).

Comment: спасибо вам большое за развернутый ответ, вы мне очень помогли!)